# Binding current foreground to Rectangle.Fill property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I'm using Mahapps Metro theme in my project. I want to create `TabControl` where `TabItem` will be image. Mahapps theme provides changing color of TabItem's text when `TabItem` is selected etc. I want to bind this foreground color to my image.
I have the solution of this problem but I think it isn't correct.

'Bad' Code (but it's working):

```
<TabItem>
   <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid Margin="0,5,0,0">
            <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" />
            <Rectangle Width="28.947" Height="25" Fill="{Binding ElementName=myTextBlock, Path=Foreground}">
               <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                  <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_image_gallery}" />
               </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            </Rectangle>
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: why do you think it's bad? I understand that you want a shape (like your transparent image) but filled with the `Foreground` of the `TextBlock`. What you do is the right approach, when it comes to shaping a complex shape defined by some image, using `OpacityMask` is the only way to go (unless you can convert the image to some SVG and then to XAML geometry data - that way is far more complex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TemplateBinding` if you don't want to bind to the inner `TextBlock`.

```
<TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Margin="0 5 0 0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            <Rectangle Width="28.947"
                        Height="25"
                        Fill="{TemplateBinding TextElement.Foreground}">
                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_image_gallery}" />
                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
```